# SSH does not work via wifi on Pi with network cable unplugged

Tags: networking, wifi, boot, ethernet

I set up wifi connection on Pi and can ssh into Pi both via LAN and wifi if the cable is plugged in on boot.
If I unplug the cable, I can no longer ssh via wifi. 
If Pi boots up with cable unplugged, I still can't ssh via wifi.

I couldn't find answer that would solve my problem in similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the solution here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/216847

It seems by default ssh process doesn't start without plugged in cable.
So /etc/init/ssh.conf should be edited this way:

```
- start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
+ start on runlevel [2345] and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
- stop on runlevel [!2345]
```

It solved my problem.