# SSH works on eth but not wifi and other services do work always

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, pi-3b+, raspbian-lite

So this is driving me crazy.

Basically my problem is that I can ssh to the pi if the ethernet cable is connected but not if disconnected.
It sounds like a typical network problem so far, but it is not:
I can ping it, I can `apt update` from wifi; I even installed later lighttpd and I can access a simple html page I created. It's just ssh the only service that doesn't want to work over wifi without the ethernet cable disconnected.

I found [this other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70193/ssh-does-not-work-via-wifi-on-pi-with-network-cable-unplugged) but I think it is not related because sshd **is** running. I can get up to the initial prompt (login, motd and prompt shown) but when I type into the terminal nothing happens, or it happens but after several tens of seconds. I can also see the process getting started when I login.

Just in case it was a client issue I tried connecting from different computers (I use linux so I just do `ssh pi@192.168.0.105`) but all show the same behavior.

The pi is very close to the router and the signal quality and strength are very good, so it is not a signal problem.

And even more crazy: When the eth cable is connected, both, using the wifi and the ethernet IP's ssh works perfectly. And the ping delay gets shortened if the cable is connected, even if I am pinging the wifi ip!

Just in case I tried also disabling the power management of the wifi with `iwconfig wlan0 power off` but I thing that it is already disabled by default always.

This is a system where I just installed **raspbian lite**, enabled shh in raspi-config, dist-upgraded and not much else.
Also, I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2.
My router does not block any port in the local network.

Anyone has seen this happening before? Any ideas on how to solve it? I have been using linux for years and never had anything like this before.

---

Edit `ip a` and `ip r`:

With ethernet connected:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxb827eb159633: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:15:96:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.106/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enxb827eb159633
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2408:210:5a5:8d00:3387:d43a:d21a:5dbf/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591866sec preferred_lft 604666sec
    inet6 fe80::a845:cbec:5d50:a017/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:40:c3:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.105/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2408:210:5a5:8d00:a898:f644:ea88:5dd0/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591866sec preferred_lft 604666sec
    inet6 fe80::9e85:4221:de76:1b54/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enxb827eb159633 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.106 metric 202 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.105 metric 303 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enxb827eb159633 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.106 metric 202 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.105 metric 303
```

**Without** ethernet connected:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxb827eb159633: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:15:96:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:40:c3:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.105/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2408:210:5a5:8d00:a898:f644:ea88:5dd0/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591691sec preferred_lft 604491sec
    inet6 fe80::9e85:4221:de76:1b54/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.105 metric 303 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.105 metric 303
```

Logs of ssh in verbose while connecting without the cable plugged in:

```
desktop:~$ ssh -v pi@192.168.0.105
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.105 [192.168.0.105] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nake/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.105:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Xjwb/7yoQctf7IE3h00o6nVBT+/g4TtQm0ZtCeYNAGc
debug1: Host '192.168.0.105' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nake/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nake/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nake/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nake/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Offering public key: ED25519 SHA256:6AJUW1IGCWvl/nSpWqgS9gQCJBIdmPULsgsFXNfxRuA /home/nake/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.0.105's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.105 ([192.168.0.105]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = es_ES.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = ja_JP.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = ja_JP.UTF-8
Linux pi 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Oct 19 15:01:52 2019 from 192.168.0.108
pi@pi:~ $
```

Several notes: It gets stuck for a few seconds after the last `debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = ja_JP.UTF-8`, before showing the motd.
After the shell is open, I can type and *sometimes* the key is shown, but most of the times it is just stuck there forever. Not even ctrl-d works most of the time, or it does after several tens of seconds.

When the connection succeeds I can see the status of sshd and the connection being open (still, without ethernet being plugged in):

```
$ systemctl status sshd
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-10-19 11:44:53 JST; 3h 26min ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 493 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2077)
   Memory: 6.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─493 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Oct 19 13:18:44 pi sshd[2892]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Oct 19 14:13:06 pi sshd[3082]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.0.108 port 46906 ssh2
Oct 19 14:13:06 pi sshd[3082]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Oct 19 14:19:28 pi sshd[3366]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.0.108 port 44942 ssh2
Oct 19 14:19:28 pi sshd[3366]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Oct 19 15:01:21 pi sshd[3546]: Connection closed by authenticating user pi 192.168.0.108 port 47032 [preauth]
Oct 19 15:01:52 pi sshd[3606]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.0.108 port 47034 ssh2
Oct 19 15:01:52 pi sshd[3606]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Oct 19 15:03:41 pi sshd[3635]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.0.108 port 47038 ssh2
Oct 19 15:03:41 pi sshd[3635]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
```

Comment: You have provided no information to help solve your problem. What OS? How did you setup networking? Is Ethernet unplugged when you boot? What do `ip a` and `ip r` show?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written it clearly: the os is raspbian buster lite. I will edit my message to add the ip results.

Comment: Networking looks OK. What happens when you enter `ssh -v pi@192.168.0.105` `systemctl status sshd` on the Pi should show connections

Comment: Nothing weird, I think. I edited the question and added the logs.

Comment: Looks like ssh works, but the response of environment settings (which look like a STRANGE mixture) probably confuse the client. The settings on the Pi should be reviewed.

Comment: Yeah, my locale is weird but it is the way I like it (I'm spanish but live in Japan).
However, I can't see how the locale would cause something like like this...
Any clue on what to check on the Pi?

Comment: What Raspbian version do you use? I guess it's Buster?

Comment: Do you ever have used before two interfaces with different ip addresses to the same subnet? If so, did it work? Can you analyze traffic with **tcpdump**?

Comment: Do you changed the hardware/RasPi? Do you have a USB/WiFi dongle available? Have you rebooted your WiFi router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a problem with the router itself.
After a full power cycle of the router it magically got fixed...

Thanks to everyone for your help!